# Why does envelope solve Hamilton-Jacobi equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $$\partial_t u+ H(Du)=0 \, \, \mbox{in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$}$$
$$ u(0, x)=g(x) \, \, \mbox{on $\mathbb{R}^n \times 0$}$$
where $H$ is smooth, convex and coercive and $g$ is Lipschitz. Can you tell me, why the envelope $v(t, x)= \mbox{inf}_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \mbox{sup}_{q \in \mathbb{R}^n} g(y)+q \cdot (x-y)- t H(q)$ solves the above initial value problem?

Comment: The explanation takes several pages in Evans' PDE book, which is a good reference. Is it possible to make the question a little more specific?